# Fn Volume up/down keys not working

Tags: kubuntu, brightness, 20.04, volume-control, media-buttons

I have just installed Kubuntu 20.04.

I want to adjust the volume using Fn + F2/F3, but it isn't quite working. It does work for adjusting the brightness of the screen and the key back lights.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you saying that `Fn`+`F2` doesn't decrease volume but instead decreases brightness?